# VB datetimepicker format as 09-SEP-2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I am trying to get datetimepicker to return the date in the following format: 08-SEP-2012.

The returned format will be part of a web address and therefore very specific.
It is set on custom formatting, and I can get the day and year right. only the 3 letter month give me a problem. Maybe there is a very simple solution but I can't find it..

I'm fairly new to Visual Basic (or any programming in general) so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Comment: VB allows you to use strings for the DateTimePicker.Value property.  It is however not a string, it is a DateTime.  Avoid using strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a date into a string in your required format, use:

```
Dim s = theDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy").ToUpper()
```